# How to integrate Constant Contact in Magento 2.3?

Tags: magento2

I need to integrate Constant Contact in `Magento 2.3`.

Is there any free extension available for this ?

Answer (score 1):

Please check below extension links.

https://www.solwininfotech.com/product/magento-2-extensions/easy-contact-form-widget-magento-2/

https://www.fmeextensions.com/quick-contact-magento-2.html

https://www.mageants.com/contact-form-extension-for-magento-2.html

Hope this will help you.

Comment: I need Constant contact https://www.constantcontact.com

Answer (score 1):

Constant contact as in this: https://www.constantcontact.com/?

If so I found this:

https://github.com/springimport/magento2-module-constantcontact

But not sure on the above. I think you will have to contact an agency to develop something for you.

Comment: I tried the above module, it is not working.

Comment: Yeah it looks like just a wrapper. So basically it gives you a starting point to develop your own solution. I'm not sure if you are going to get something for free.